# Query for Joining three tables with row value as column header

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have three tables as shown below.

```
TABLE1 : tb_subject
subject_id  subject_name
  1          English
  2          Maths
  3          Science

Table2 : tb_student
subject_id  student_id 
    1         AA        
    1         BB
    2         CC
    3         DD
    3         EE

  Table3 : tb_student_score
   student_id  score  conducted_month_number
      AA         20          2
      BB         30          3
      CC         50          4
      AA         80          4
      DD         50          6
      BB         10          2
      EE         40          3
```

Result should be

```
  conducted_month_number SUM(subject_id1)  SUM(subject_id2)  SUM(subject_id3) 
         1                   0                  0                   0
         2                  30                  0                   0
         3                  30                  0                  40
         4                  80                 50                   0
         5                   0                  0                   0
         6                   0                  0                  60
         7                   0                  0                   0
         8                   0                  0                   0
         9                   0                  0                   0
         10                  0                  0                   0
         11                  0                  0                   0
         12                  0                  0                   0
```

How to write a select query for this? Can add all month number that is not stored in table as like in the resulted output?

Comment: sql server 2005

Comment: Do you have any code yet? Are there a known(fixed) number of subjects or are they variable?

Comment: subject_id1 in 4. month is not 50  can you check it

Comment: In future, there may be chance for adding new subject_ids to ' tb_subject' table .

Comment: subject_id3 in 6.month is 50 can you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `case when` to sum for each subject individually:

```
SELECT conducted_month_number,
       SUM(CASE b.subject_id WHEN 1 THEN a.score ELSE 0 END) AS English,
       SUM(CASE b.subject_id WHEN 2 THEN a.score ELSE 0 END) AS Maths,
       SUM(CASE b.subject_id WHEN 3 THEN a.score ELSE 0 END) AS Science
FROM tb_student_score AS a
  JOIN tb_student AS b ON b.student_id = a.student_id
GROUP BY conducted_month_number
ORDER BY conducted_month_number;
```

However, this alone will not ensure you have results for values of `conducted_month_number` that don't exist - if this is an issue, you could simply create a dummy student with a score of 0 for each month.

Edit: I noticed some comments posted around the same time I submitted my answer - if you want the number of summation columns to be variable based on the values of rows in the tb_subject table, you will not find the relational model of `SQL` to be well suited for that task.  However, you can easily go back and update your query to include any new subjects you may add later on.

Answer (score 3):

Have added `dummy values` of 1 to 12 months using `union statement` and later on did `group by` on them to calculate total scores.

Try this:-

```
Select conducted_month_number ,
sum(case when subject_id=1 then score else 0 end) as sum_subject_id1,
sum(case when subject_id=2 then score else 0 end) as sum_subject_id2,
sum(case when subject_id=3 then score else 0 end) as sum_subject_id3
from
(
Select a.conducted_month_number ,subject_id,score
from
tb_student_score a
inner join 
tb_student b
on a.student_id=b.student_id
union 
select 1,' ',0 from tb_student_score
union 
select 2,' ',0 from tb_student_score
union 
select 3,' ',0 from tb_student_score
union 
select 4,' ',0 from tb_student_score
union 
select 5,' ',0 from tb_student_score
union 
select 6,' ',0 from tb_student_score
union 
select 7,' ',0  from tb_student_score
union 
select 8,' ',0 from tb_student_score
union 
select 9,' ',0  from tb_student_score
union 
select 10,' ',0  from tb_student_score
union 
select 11,' ',0  from tb_student_score
union 
select 12,' ',0 from tb_student_score
)a
group by conducted_month_number

My Output

conducted_month_number  sum_subject_id1 sum_subject_id2 sum_subject_id3
               1              0               0             0
               2              30              0             0
               3              30              0             40
               4              80              50            0
               5              0               0             0
               6              0               0             50
               7              0               0             0
               8              0               0             0
               9              0               0             0
              10              0               0             0   
              11              0               0             0   
              12              0               0             0
```